# Check files modification from a process with Python watchdog

Tags: python, file, process, watchdog

I'm trying to use Python watchdog and I don't know if it's possible to check if a process modified/created/deleted files, can anyone help me?

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=' %(message)s')
path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'

event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)

observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

How can I change the code to show the process that changed files in a specific folder?

Comment: What have you already tried, and what was the exact problem that you are having?

Comment: how can I change the code to show the process that changed files in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I change the code to show the process that changed files in a specific folder?

You can't :(

Observer class is using [scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) for modified/created/deleted files/folders and that's all.
To get the information about which process is modifying a file, you probably need to use same OS specyfic tools like [Windows system access control list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists) or [linux auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl)